# ReactJS Theme Advice

Tags: reactjs

#### Context

I want to dynamically change the colors of all components depending on the user's selection.

---

#### Question

How would you recommend structuring the code in order to do this?

Comment: React's new context API is a good way to go about this. The official docs have a simple example: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks